# Wrapper efficiency: Vector of pointers vs vector of objects

Tags: c++

This snippet of code implements a `Detection` object and a `DetectionHandler` that contains an array of objects `std::vector<Detection>`,

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <vector>
#include <string>


class Detection {
    
private:
    
    int id;
 
public:
    int x, y;
    Detection (int const& cx,int const& cy,int const& cid)
    {
        x  = cx;
        y  = cy;
        id = cid;
    }
    void update(int const& X,int const& Y)
    {
        x = X;
        y = Y;
    }
    
    void show() 
    { 
        std::cout <<"id: "<< id << " x: " << x << " y: " << y << std::endl; 
    }
};


class DetectionHandler
{
    private:
        int ids = 0;
   
    public:
        std::vector<Detection> list;
        
        void append(Detection const& D)
        {
            list.push_back(D);
        }

        void pop(int const& i)
        {
            list.erase( list.begin()+i);
        }

        void tracking(int const x, int const y)
        {

            bool tracked = false;
            for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
            {
                if (list[i].x - x < 5   &&   list[i].y - y < 5)
                {
                    tracked = true;
                    list[i].update(x,y);
                }

            }

            if (!tracked)
            {
                ids++;
                append(Detection(x,y,ids));
            }
               
        }
};


int main()
{
    DetectionHandler detectionHandler;

    for ( int i=1;i<20;i++)
    {
        int x = 1 + (rand() % 300);
        int y = 1 + (rand() % 300);

        if (detectionHandler.list.size() == 0)
        {
            detectionHandler.append(Detection(x,y,0));
        }
        else
        {
            detectionHandler.tracking(x,y);
        }
            
    }

    for (int i=0; i<detectionHandler.list.size();i++)
    {
        detectionHandler.list[i].show();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

i want to know if i will gain any efficiency by using pointers in this context.

Comment: Why do you think storing pointers would be more efficient? Can you describe what you mean by more efficient?

Comment: faster to iterate (like in the last loop) and less memory consumption. But i’m not sure. My goal is to make this structure be the most efficient and fast as possible. Do you spot anything you think that can be better implemented?

Comment: You seem to have a very vague goal. You wrapped up a vector in a class, therefore you're as "efficient" as vector is. Optimizing your iterations in your last loop doesn't even make sense since it's I/O bound since it writes to console. **Suggestion:** Write the code you need to solve the actual task you're working on. If you see a bottleneck, _then_ optimize.

Comment: i made this to illustrate the problem. I want this structure where a class wrappers a list/array of one other object. Is this the best way i can do it, or you think i should look to implement it in other way? as you stated, i’m bound to std::vector efficiency, so should i go to use only array if want to improve this? (even think it doesn’t have a standard size return method, have fixed length etc …)

Comment: If you're interested in efficiency consider passing ints by value and using the initializer list in your constructor.

Comment: @GuintherKovalski *"less memory consumption"* -- why would storing an object plus a pointer to it consume less memory than storing just the object?

Comment: The program's calculation can be done fully in compile-time(Though the random is used, but not seeded, so it's deterministic), this would be the most efficient way, but is it worthy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Storing pointers in your vector is usually *less* efficient than storing the objects directly, for the following reasons:

1. In most cases, you end up having to do a separate heap-allocation for each object (i.e. one `new` to create the object before adding a pointer to the object to the vector, and one `delete` after removing the object from the vector, in order to avoid a memory-leak).  Each separate heap-allocation adds additional overhead, both in terms of CPU cycles to manage the heap, and in terms of memory, since each heap-allocation eats up not only the payload-bytes but also some behind-the-scenes metadata bytes to track the allocation.
2. Iterating over a vector of objects can be very cache-efficient, since the CPU is reading/writing memory in a linear fashion and that maximizes [locality-of-reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality_of_reference).  Iterating over a vector of pointers and dereferencing each of them, OTOH, usually means the CPU is reading/writing memory from various semi-arbitrary locations in the heap, which can cause a lot of cache misses.  On modern hardware where RAM latency is slow relative to CPU speed, this can slow things down significantly.

Also, doing separate memory allocations for each object is tricky and often results in memory leaks if you aren't careful.  One reason you might want to store objects by pointer anyway is if you need polymorphism (e.g. your objects are not all the same type, but rather may be of various subclasses of a single superclass instead); in that case, pointers are required.  Another reason would be if your objects are *very* large (e.g. multiple kilobytes per object, or more), which might make it worth the extra overhead to avoid ever copying them.  (you'd have to benchmark and see, though)

Note that if you know in advance how many objects you are going to add to your vector, you can avoid unnecessary memory-reallocations while populating the vector by calling [reserve()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve) on the vector first, so that the vector knows how big of an internal array to allocate up-front.  If you can do that, your vector will be as efficient as a primitive (C-style) C++ array, while also being easier and safer to work with.

Comment: thank you so much for the answer, you get straight to the point (I don't get why i got so many downvotes). Do you think that this code can benefit from member list initialization or templates?

Comment: Those things could be added; whether or not the code benefits from them depends on what you want to use the code for.  (if you think it would be useful to have those things, go for it, but don't add features to your code just for the sake of adding them, unless you are doing it as a way to learn how those features work)

Comment: Thank you for have some good will in actually answering this question. And i have to add that the c++ community in stackoverflow is one of the worst places to ask anything about c++. Reddit is a way less toxic place to learn and ask question on the subject, really recommend: https://www.reddit.com/r/cpp_questions/